# Node.js: messed up Paths to external resources due to URL encoded GET parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Depending on incoming client GET request, I return prepared HTML sites based on the `res.sendfile` instruction. So far everything works fine.

But now, I introdced an extended GET route, featuring a URL encoded parameter (verificationcode).

```
app.get('/validateuser/:verificationcode/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname+"/public/valiuser.html");
});
```

Looking at the served HTML site (`valiuser.html`) in the browser, it appears that all paths to linked external resources (images, css files, javascript files, ...) are lost. Once I change the route to:

```
app.get('/validateuser', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname+"/public/valiuser.html");
});
```

Everything works all fine. Why is this additional GET parameter messing up my paths?

The code above is located in my **server.js** file. On the same level, I have a public folder containing the html files and other "external resources".

Here is an excerpt from **valiuser.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/general.css">
    <script src="public/js/top.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="public/images/logo.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, Igor

Comment: Are you using relative paths for the `images`, `css`, and `js`? Show us the `valiuser.html`.

Comment: Ensure that you are using absolute paths in your html file.

Comment: Your paths are relative to whatever the path of the current page is.  You changed that current page path, so of course your relative paths no longer align.  Use your browser's developer tools to investigate problems like these and you will see immediately what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are relative to path of your current page.

To make your life easier you may want to use `express.static` to serve up your static files (If you have not already).
For your last route use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This will catch any route not caught by your other routes and see if a static file exists in your public directory.

Then in your **valiuser.html** change your paths:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/general.css">
    <script src="/js/top.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img src="/images/logo.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```